# Iterable<Path> vs Path

Tags: java, path, iterable

Why would not it be possible to place an iterable object into a Path reference (which implements Iterable?

```
Iterable<Path> dirs = FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories();
for (Path name: dirs) {
    System.err.println(name);
}
```

If I change `Iterable<Path>` with `Path` it does give me a compilation error. Why? Should not it be more program-to-interface minded?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you add explanation of what you think you should be able to write, and what you expect it to do.

Comment: `Path` is more specialized than `Iterable<Path>` - thus if `getRootDirectories()` only contracts `Iterable<Path>` you can't assign it to the more special kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looking at the `java.nio.file` API docs:

```
public interface Path
    extends Comparable<Path>, Iterable<Path>, Watchable
```

So a `Path` is an `Iterable<Path>`. What does that mean? The obvious interpretation is that there is a central concept of recursive hierarchy. This isn't the case. The API is a little confused. A `Path` can be composed as a series of atomic elements. e.g I guess `/etc/passwd` is a sequence `(etc, passwd)`. Clearly we have more than one concept here, but the modelling is weak.

So `FileSystem.getRootDirectories` is going to return a set (don't know why it's `Iterable` only) a fully qualified paths. (e.g. I guess `(C:\, D:\, Z:\)`.) Each element of the set is going to be (should be have) a sequence of path atoms. It wouldn't make sense for `getRoorDirectories` to return a single `Path` which has full-qualified path names as its elements. Hopefully a cast of the returned `Iterable` to `Path` should fail.

Answer (score 1):

Path IS-A Iterable but Iterable IS NOT Path.
So you need to do type casting

Comment: Really that cast should fail!